# Validate require if checkbox option is X

Tags: jquery, checkbox, require, selected

I am working on a form that requires validation. A small part of the form requires the user to choose between 2 options "Yes", "No". When no is selected I would need them to enter a reason, and otherwise if yes is selected, I don't need a reason (even the inputfield may be hidden then <- this is only doable via JavaScript I guess?)

How would I have to create this rule?

Let's say the part of the form looks like this

```html
<form  id="Form" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>form</legend>
    Yes:
        <input name="choice" type="radio" value="Yes"/>
        <br />
    No:
        <input name="choice" type="radio" value="No"/>
        <br />
        <label for="reaason">Reason</label>
        <input id="reason" name="reason"  />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZYqyC/

wrapping label and textbox in a div

```
<div id=reasondiv>
            <label for="reaason">Reason</label>
            <input id="reason" name="reason"  />
 </div>
```

then jquery:

```
$("#reasondiv").hide();
$("input[name=choice]:radio").click(function(){

   if($(this).val()=='Yes')
      $("#reasondiv").show();
   else
       $("#reasondiv").hide();

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this

```
$('input[name="choice"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'No'){
        $('.reason').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.reason').hide();
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/fh2Q9/

Note: I changed the HTML a bit, giving the "reason" `input` and `label` a class, so it was easier to hide.

Comment: That might just work, I will test this to see if it doesn't create problems with the validation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I suspected, even if the reason label is hidden, the jquery validate still wants a value for it. My rule looks like this     $("#newform").validate({ rules:{reason:{required:true}} });

I will probably have to edit this so that reason is only required when radio has value Yes. Any ideas?

Comment: @logistef, you should be able to modify the rule to include a `dependency-callback`.  See this http://rocketsquared.com/wiki/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-callback

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/KJCDS/

I had to modify the html a little.

html:

```
<form  id="Form" method="get" action="">
<fieldset>
<legend>form</legend>
Yes:<input name="choice" type="radio" value="Yes" checked='true'/><br>
No:<input name="choice" type="radio" id='rdoNo' value="No"/><br>
<label id="lblReason" for="reaason">Reason</label>
<input id="reason" name="reason"  />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

JS (using jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#reason').hide();
    $('#lblReason').hide();

    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
        if($('#rdoNo').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('#reason').show();
            $('#lblReason').show();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#reason').hide();
             $('#lblReason').hide();
        }

        ;});
});
```